# how to export a query data to txt file without saving query on MS access

Tags: vba, ms-access

as i need to export multiple queries data to .txt file i have to save every queries , is there any way to export query data to .txt file without saving it on ms access.

Thank you

Comment: There are many, many ways to achieve this, for example using Recordsets and Excel. Your current question is too broad. Please share an attempt, and any errors you encounter

Answer (score 1):

You can manage with one query only:

```
Dim Query As DAO.QueryDef
Dim SQL   As String

Set Query = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("ExportQuery")

' First export.
SQL = <some sql to export>
Query.SQL = SQL
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "ExportQuery", "d:\folder\file1.txt"

' Second export.
SQL = <some other sql to export>
Query.SQL = SQL
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "ExportQuery", "d:\folder\file2.txt"

' etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "Categories", "C:\your_path_here\names.txt", True
End Sub
```

Categories is the object you want to export from; Table, Query, etc.

Answer (score 0):

thanks Gustav and ryguy72,

after some research on net i found an answer is just puting a code between my query. Normally when i switch to sql view from design view, code looks like below-

`SELECT [0_Users_Balance].MSISDN, [0_Users_Balance].ZONE
FROM 0_Users_Balance;`

to export a query result without saving that query i have to insert below code only - `into [Text;DATABASE=C:\Temp\;].File_Name.txt`

that will looks like below -

`SELECT [0_Users_Balance].MSISDN, [0_Users_Balance].ZONE
into [Text;DATABASE=C:\Temp\;].File_Name.txt
FROM 0_Users_Balance;`